# Deleting zeroth element in vector taking more time

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a real time problem. I'm using vector for my problem. The problem is 90% of time I have to traverse the list. 5% of time I have to `push_back` data to the list. 1% time I have to delete. But in that list if I have more than 1GB of data then to delete 0th element it is taking more than 2 min and system get hung. How can I avoid it, or any other Standard Template Library can solve my problem?

Comment: `deque` would allow fast erasure of the first element. So would `list`, but the overhead might be too large. Both might be slower to traverse, though.

Comment: yes @MikeSeymour ... but i need faster access because of traversing.

Comment: Are you traversing or performing random access?

Comment: @Nihar: Did you even try `deque`, though?

Comment: yes @BartvanNierop .. needing random access.

Comment: You might want to edit that fact into your question, as it makes a pretty significant difference in possible solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the first solution is the easiest. Use a different data structure. A `std::deque` for example.

Let's say that for some reason, a `std::deque` won't work. But in addition, you can reorder your elements. If that is the case, then let's do this:

```
void remove(std::vector<T> elems, int index) {
    swap(elems[index], elems.back());
    elems.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: To readers unfamiliar with this technique: it's the "swap-and-pop" idiom.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Thanks. I wasn't actually aware it had a name.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. As suggested by [MikeSeymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) use a `deque`
2. Keep your own pointer to your `vector`'s begin if you just need to delete the first elements
3. Use `copy` and then `resize`

Example of #3, say I need to remove 3 elements:

```
replace(foo.begin(), advance(foo.begin(), 3), advance(foo.end(), -3), foo.end());
foo.resize(foo.size() - 3);
```

Comment: Note, though, that you'll need to update this pointer every time you `push_back` (or modify the `vector` in any way), or else it might be an invalid pointer. You may want to just use an offset instead of a pointer and just do `begin() + offset` rather than keeping an actual pointer.

Comment: @Cornstalks That's a good call. That's clearly the worst of the three options, cause you have some nasty data-mirroring problems. But then the best solution is just use a `deque` but [Nihar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3479893/nihar) seems to be opposed to it.